# Error: Cannot find module 'node-jsdom

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I have two files todosController.js and index.html. I am trying to access an element and see the output of it in javascript console. here is the code:

```
<!--index.html:--> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TodosList</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Todos List</h1>
   <button id="displayTodosButton">Display Todos</button>
   <!--index.html is linked to javascript file todosController.js-->
   <script src="todosController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is JavaScript code:

```
  //todosController.js

var jsdom = require("node-jsdom");
var fs = require("fs");
var jquery = fs.readFileSync("./jquery.js", "utf-8");

jsdom.env({
url: "http://news.ycombinator.com/",
src: [jquery],
done: function (errors, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    console.log("HN Links");
    $("td.title:not(:last) a").each(function () {
        console.log(" -", $(this).text());
    });
}
});
let markup = fs.readFileSync('foo.html');
let doc = jsdom(markup, {});

function showData() {
    elem = doc.getElementById('TodosText').value;
}

showData();
```

I am using Webstorm as an IDE.I tried to install npm jsdom as recommeded in some of the answers below but the issue is still the same.

Here is the error:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-jsdom'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> 
   (/Users/muhammadtayyabsaeed/WebstormProjects/Todo 
   List/js/todosController.js:89:13)
   at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
   at  Module.load (module.js:554:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

I would appreciate your response.

Comment: Are you running the code in a browser ?

Comment: `js folder, which has todosController.js.` You are saying you have js folder but I can't see that in your `src`??

Comment: with console, do you mean browser console or js/node console?

Comment: I just tried your code on my system. It is working fine

Comment: It seems like your compiler is targeting a non-browser environment, like nodejs.

Comment: I checked it using plunker on chrome and it works perfect there ... but not in webstorm. @Sanchit Patiyal ... I missed the folder path but even if i remove it from js folder and put it directly in the project, it still doesn't work...

Comment: @Tayyab So, you are running the code with something in WebStorm, right ?

Comment: @Taurus I am using the console of the webstorm to see the output of javascript.

Comment: @tincot I have can solve it if it is targeting a non-browser environment? I get the output of other elements in the javascript console of webstorm in the same file of javascript but that is not part of this question.

Comment: what 'javascript console' are you talking about?

Comment: The console that displays javascript result using node in the Webstorm IDE @lena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try creating the following project in WebStorm:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "node_dom",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jsdom": "^11.3.0"
  }
}
```

**todosController.js**

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");
const jsdom_hard = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js").jsdom;
const fs = require('fs');

jsdom.env(
  "http://news.ycombinator.com/",
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function(err, window) {
    const $ = window.$;
    console.log("HN Links");
    $("td.title:not(:last) a").each(function() {
      console.log(" -", $(this).text());
    });
  }
);

let markup = fs.readFileSync('foo.html');
let doc = jsdom_hard(markup, {});


function showData() {
  elem = doc.getElementById('TodosText').innerHTML;
  console.log("Element value: " + elem)
}

showData();
```

**foo.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TodosList</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="TodosText">Hello!!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

- right-click the **package.json**, choose `Run "npm install"`
- once dependencies are installed, right-click the **todosController.js**, choose `Run`

this should do the thing

Comment: I am getting an error at this line `const jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");`
Here are the following problems I get with them. I am not getting output when I add some buttons to do some event listening 
` let displayTodosButton = doc.getElementById('displayTodosButton');
console.log(displayTodosButton);`
 It doesn't work. Also when I put some functions for declaration in the code they don't give any output in the browser console, while they do in the webstrom console. When I put the same methods declarations in the browser console then they give output... its very confusing..

Comment: here is the link to the repo where I just put the code to support my above comment for further clarifications: https://github.com/MTayyabSaeed/todos-list-javascript ... I did the same way as you explained above...

Comment: what error do you see at "require" line? And why do you expect to see anything in browser console? Also, `console.log(displayTodosButton)` is not a listener, it just outputs HTMLElement

Comment: The error for `const jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");` is `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. `console.log(displayTodosButton)` I know this outputs HTMLElement, but when I am using actionlisteners on `displayTodosButton` it doesn't give any output, even for other code. When I run it I get the above error.

Comment: this error indicates that you are running this code in browser instead of Node.js. This code is not intended to be run in browser. jsdom module is a node.js implementation of DOM interface that allows emulating browser environment when running Node.js. So, what is your goal? What application are you trying to create? You are doing weird things, your comments make me feel totally lost

Comment: Well I am creating a todo list using webstorm as an IDE. I am checking the output of all the code in console of the browser but also check the output in the webstorm as well. With the browser my code original code worked fine but I wanted to run it in webstorm node. Thats what I want to do.

Comment: Code written for browser has to be run in browser. Code written for Node.js should be run with Node.js. That's all. And has nothing to do with the IDE. This is my last answer in this thread

Comment: I take this answer.I learned a lot from this thread. I don't know how to make the question better so it will be marked positive so it will be helpful for others as per stackoverflow says and i would be able to to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I twisted your code a little bit, so here it goes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TodosList</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Todos List</h1>
  <input type="text" id="TodosText">
  <input type="button" id="displayTodosButton" value="Display Todos" onClick="showData();">

  <script>
    function showData() {
      elem = document.getElementById('TodosText').value;
      console.log(elem);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In this sample I put the script in the html file but feel free to use as you wish.
Also added a text field and changed the button to a simple html one and the call to showData on it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My code works in the browser but not in webstrom. So your solution doesn't help the prolem since I tried to modify it according to what I need. I don't want to use script inside of the html.

Comment: Sorry @Tayyab, you are right, also I didn't noted about Webstorm! my bad.

Comment: webstorm doesn't run the code, so the statement 'code doesn't work in webstorm' makes no sense. Seems that you are running your code with node.js instead of loading it in browser. **Run** command in javascript file right-click menu runs it with Node.js. **Run** command in HTML file right-click menu opens application in browser

Comment: I already know what you are talking about. Please read my question again. And I don't need help for how to run files. It's a big file I am running and everything works except the one I have asked for here. @lena

Comment: @lena as per your reputation for webstorm, I can hope that you can tell me exactly how to run DOM components in Node.js -- `document.getElementById()`

Comment: the errors you can see clearly indicate that the corresponding node module ('node-jsdom' or 'jsdom') is not installed. Unfortunately I have been unable to install node-jsdom on my system - it requires having MS Visual studio installed. But everything works fine using jsdom. I'll add one more answer, as I can't insrt code snippets in comments

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the beginning of your JS and run the JS file instead of running HTML (replace `foo.html` with the path from your JS file to your HTML file):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom; 
var markup = fs.readFileSync('foo.html');
var doc = jsdom(markup, {});
```

Then try accessing the `document` as `doc` instead and see if that works.

The thing is, `document` is only defined in browser environments, not in the WebStorm console, which is why your code is working in Chrome (I am not an expert on WebStorm, but I believe it runs JS code in a nodeJS environment where a `document` is not defined).

Take a look at [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206324229-How-can-I-feed-an-HTML-document-to-WebStorm-for-processing) thread (which is also where I snatched the above example from).

Comment: I am getting this Error: 
module.js:529
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'jsdom'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (List/js/todosController.js:89:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)

Comment: Then you need to include the ["jsdom"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsdom) Node module.

Comment: I tried to install on my mac but got a lot of erros while installing. so the installation is full of errors now. Then I tried to run it, it didn't worked. Then I included their code which they proposed the similar way as you did but still no luck. @Taurus